# activator clean failing while building play framework project

Tags: docker, scala, playframework, sbt

This all is being done in docker, not sure where it is failing as Im new to scala and sbt.
Error while doing activator clean.
Not sure where `http` is being added from

```
#25 7.062 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-fork-run-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml
#25 7.851 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-fork-run-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml
#25 18.62 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-fork-run-protocol_2.10/2.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml
#25 20.98 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-fork-run-protocol_2.10/2.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml
#25 26.31 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-fork-run-protocol_2.10/2.3.10/jars/sbt-fork-run-protocol_2.10.jar
#25 27.20 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-fork-run-protocol_2.10/2.3.10/jars/sbt-fork-run-protocol_2.10.jar
#25 32.55 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml
#25 33.37 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.10/ivys/ivy.xml
#25 37.00 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.10/jars/sbt-run-support_2.10.jar
#25 37.88 [error] Server access Error: Unexpected end of file from server url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.10/jars/sbt-run-support_2.10.jar
....
#25 1301.1 [warn]   [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar (2ms)
#25 1301.1 [warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
#25 1301.1 [warn]   file:/usr/local/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.7/jars/commons-compress.jar
#25 1301.1 [warn]   [NOT FOUND  ] org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar (0ms)
#25 1301.1 [warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
#25 1301.1 [warn]   file:/usr/local/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository/org.tukaani/xz/1.4/jars/xz.jar
#25 1349.6 [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#25 1349.6 [warn]   ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
#25 1349.6 [warn]   :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
#25 1349.6 [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#25 1349.6 [warn]   :: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar
#25 1349.6 [warn]   :: org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar
#25 1349.6 [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#25 1349.9 sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar
#25 1349.9 download failed: org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
#25 1349.9  at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
#25 1349.9  at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
#25 1349.9  at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
#25 1349.9  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
#25 1349.9  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
#25 1349.9  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
#25 1349.9  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
#25 1349.9  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
#25 1349.9  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
#25 1349.9 [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.7!commons-compress.jar
#25 1349.9 [error] download failed: org.tukaani#xz;1.4!xz.jar
#25 1350.0 Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

plugins.sbt file

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.2.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.3.2")
```

repositories in ~/.sbt.
This I've copied from local env and added to the dockerfile

```
[repositories]
  local
  activator-launcher-local: file://${activator.local.repository-${activator.home-${user.home}/.activator}/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  activator-local: file://${activator.local.repository-/Users/ishaankanwar/br/tools/activator-dist-1.3.12/repository}, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-releases-repo: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
  typesafe-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases
  typesafe-ivy-releasez: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

Comment: This "unexpected end of file" looks as if you firewall or docker configuration blocked you from accessing repositories. Try running some curl commandnin docker to download a file you know exists.

Comment: I feel like it should be `https` instead of `http`, is there any way we can change the http call to https